# ¿Cómo cambiar levels y labels para una variable en R?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, revisión-de-código, variables

Tengo la siguiente variable:

```
str(mod$sexo)
Factor w/ 2 levels "H","M": 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
```

Y quiero convertirla de tal forma que la salida en consola sea la siguiente:

```
str(mod$sexo)
Factor w/ 2 levels "Hombre","Mujer": 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
```

Es decir, cambiar tanto las etiquetas como la codifcación de la variable. He intentado

```
mod$sexo <- as.numeric(mod$sexo== "M")
levels(mod$sexo) <- c(levels(mod$sexo), "Hombre", "Mujer")
```

Que me produce la siguiente salida:

```
str(mod$sexo)
atomic [1:331405] 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:2] "Hombre" "Mujer"
```

Sin embargo, cuando la tabulo, aparece como:

```
table(mod$sexo)

     0      1 
167298 164107
```

Evidentemente, el resultado no es el esperado.

Cualquier orientación, la agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma básica de modificar las etiquetas de cualquier factor es mediante [`levels()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/levels.html), pero no como lo estás haciendo sino así:

```
> df <- data.frame(sexo=sample(c("H","M"),10, replace = TRUE))
> str(df)

'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ sexo: Factor w/ 2 levels "H","M": 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1

> levels(df$sexo)
[1] "H" "M"

> levels(df$sexo) <- c("Hombre", "Mujer") # Respetar el orden
> levels(df$sexo)
[1] "Hombre" "Mujer" 

> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ sexo: Factor w/ 2 levels "Hombre","Mujer": 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2
```

**Edición:**

Leyendo tu comentario entiendo que lo que buscas es crear un `Factor` cuyo `level` de inicio sea `0` y no `1`. Veamos un ejemplo de esto con el `data.frame` anterior. Haciendo: `dput(df)` obtenemos algo como esto:

```
structure(list(sexo = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = "sexo", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Si editamos a mano el vector numérico para forzar `0` y `1` así

```
structure(list(sexo = structure(c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L), .Label = c("H", "M"), class = "factor")), .Names = "sexo", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Y si lo intentamos ejecutar obtenemos un hermoso error: **`Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor`**. Resumiendo no es posible lo que buscas, ¿por que? básicamente por que **R**, a diferencia de otros lenguajes cómo C, el índice inicial de cualquier objeto es `1` y no `0`. En el caso de un `Factor` un índice `0` es inconsistente con la lista de etiquetas que como dijimos su índice inicial es `1`.

Comment: ¿Y para cambiar los 2 por 0 y dejar los 1 como están qué debo hacer? Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera Me temo que no puedes, o al menos no conozco una forma accesible de hacerlo, la numeración interna de los factores comienza desde 1 (como casi todo en R), por lo que si quieres 1 o 0 en lugar de 1 y 2 podrias transforma la columna en númerico así `as.numeric(df$sexo)-1`

Comment: @AlejandroCarrera, ahí edite la respuesta con una explicación creo que más clara.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio :)